# Why do I get a compilation error when calling println method in the class body? #Java

Tags: oop, constructor, println

```
class Test {
    int a = 100;
    System.out.println(a); 
}
class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test t = new Test();
    }
}
```

I'm new to programming. I found this code when I'm practicing. I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

Here is the error I'm getting.

```
Demo.java:3: error: <identifier> expected
 System.out.println(a);
                   ^
Demo.java:3: error: <identifier> expected
 System.out.println(a);
                     ^
2 errors
Compilation failed.
```

Can you guys explain why I'm getting this error?

Comment: When asking "why is this an error?" questions, you should always post the actual error message.

Comment: Why do you think there shouldn't be an error at that line?

Comment: When do you think `System.out.println(a);` should be executed? Why do you think so?

Comment: No. I can't remove people's downvotes. You can read the help center and learn how to ask questions on this site. You can also edit and delete your questions.

Comment: I disagree with the close reason. It appears that he asked the question because he misunderstood how Java classes work. I could imagine future users with the same problem finding this question. I'll edit to give it a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a method directly from the `java class body`.

Create a constructor in your `Test` class, and put the `print` in it :

```
class Test {
    int a = 100;

    public Test() {
        System.out.println(a); 
    }
}
```

Note that if for some reason you really want a statement to be executed when the class is loaded without using a constructor, you can define a `static` block, here an example :

```
class Test {
    static int a = 100;

    static {
        System.out.println(a); 
    }

}
```

However, this is just for reference and really not needed in your case.

Comment: Yes, it's because the code needs to be in a method or constructor. But note that adding code with side effects (like printing things to the screen) to constructors is not a good practice.

Comment: @DhanukaLakshan I am not one of the people who downvoted your question.

Answer (score 0):

From [Declaring Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html) in the Java tutorial:

> In general, class declarations can include these components, in order:
>
> 1. Modifiers such as public, private, and a number of others that you will encounter later.
> 2. The class name, with the initial letter capitalized by convention.
> 3. The name of the class's parent (superclass), if any, preceded by the keyword extends. A class can only extend (subclass) one parent.
> 4. A comma-separated list of interfaces implemented by the class, if any, preceded by the keyword implements. A class can implement more than one interface.
> 5. The class body, surrounded by braces, {}.

You can't make any function calls outside of a method declaration.